# Data sharing between Akka actors

Tags: scala, slick

Based on this question [Data sharing in Akka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52006036/data-sharing-in-akka) I've implemented a simple akka hierarchy to share data between two actors:

```
package playground

import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRef, ActorSystem, Props}

case object GetFromDb
case object GetList
case object ProcessList

class ParentActor extends Actor {
  var fromDb: List[Int] = List()

  def receive = {
    case GetFromDb =>
      // query the database and replace fromDb with a new list
      fromDb = List(1,2,3)

    case GetList =>
      sender() ! fromDb
  }
}

class ChildActor(parent: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case ProcessList =>
      // get the list from the parent
      parent ! GetList
    case fromDb: List[Int] =>
      fromDb.foreach(println)
  }
}

object AkkaDataSharingDriver extends App {

  val system: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("as")
  implicit val ec = system.dispatcher

  val parentActorRef: ActorRef = system.actorOf(Props(new ParentActor()))
  val childActorRef: ActorRef = system.actorOf(Props(new ChildActor(parentActorRef)))

  parentActorRef ! GetFromDb
  parentActorRef ! GetList

  childActorRef ! ProcessList

}
```

The List values 1,2,3 are printed so it appears the message `fromDb` is sent to `ChildActor` causing this `foreach` to be invoked :

```
case fromDb: List[Int] =>
      fromDb.foreach(println)
```

But as the message with `fromDb` is never explicitly sent what is causing

```
fromDb.foreach(println)
```

to be invoked ? Is it somehow sent implicitly ?

Comment: the sender() property in your parent actor references to the child. You are sending the list to print through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child/parent naming is rather confusing since there is no parent/child relationship in this code. Better to call them something like DbProvider and DbClient.

The sequence is this:

1. The app sends `ProcessList` to the child actor (`childActorRef ! ProcessList`)
2. The child actor sends `GetList` to the parent actor (`parent ! GetList`)
3. The parent actor replies to the child actor with the db (`sender() ! fromDb`)
4. The child actor receives the db and prints it out

Note that there is a race condition in this code and theoretically the db could be `List()` rather than `List(1,2,3)`.

---

The only delivery guarantee in Akka is that two messages sent from one actor to the same actor will be processed in the order they were sent. Otherwise messages can be processed in any order and, in particular, messages sent via a third actor can overtake messages that are sent directly.

In this case the `ProcessList` message could be processed by the `ChildActor` and the resulting `GetList` message could be processed by the `ParentActor` before the `GetFromDb` message from the app is processed by the `ParentActor`. If this happens, the reply to `GetList` would contain the default DB value.

Comment: a race condition can occur as Akka utilizes "at-most-once delivery" therefore if the message GetFromDb is not delivered db could be List() ? If this occurs I can try re-sending the GetFromDb message ?

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain why there is a race condition.